# Symfony 3 Project Structure when using Vuejs+Webpack

Tags: symfony, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

I am just about to build an application that will consist of a rest api for the backend which is then consumed by a vuejs application.

I would like the frontend and backend code to be in the same code repository.

I am just struggling to figure out where to put my vuejs files.

Currently my project directory structure looks like this:

```
/project-dir
    /app
    /bin
    /src
    /tests
    /var
    /vendor
    /web
```

Now do I put all the js files in /project-dir/web? Like this:

```
/project-dir
    /app
    /bin
    /src
    /tests
    /var
    /vendor
    /web
        /build
        /config
        /node_modules
        package.json
        /src
        /static
        /test
```

I feel this might be a good way to structure it but not sure if there are any downsides with doing it this way. How would you integrate vuejs and webpack into a skeleton symfony application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you build your vue.js project (and the folder web/builds/ suggests it). I would recommend keeping the rest of the code outside the web/ directory and build into it.

Other than that there is nothing speaking against your approach and it's even suggested by the current [Symfony Best Practices](https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html):

> Best Practice
>
> Store your assets in the web/ directory.